# Magento 2.3 and Matomo (Piwik)

Tags: magento2

I just tried to upgrade from Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3 and composer wouldn't let me because of the Matomo extension fron henek. So for now some dependency restrictions seem to prevent an upgrade.

https://github.com/henkelund/magento2-henhed-piwik

Any ideas to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2.3 & above use https://github.com/fnogatz/magento2-matomo .

Also, inside you can find note there

> NOTE: If you're using a Magento version prior to 2.2 you'll need to
> stick to the 1.x releases of the original
> [Henhed_Piwik](https://github.com/henkelund/magento2-henhed-piwik#installation).

Answer (score 0):

Composer's `replace` may be helpful.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace